# The easiest way to connect Apache Kafka and Oracle DB in Docker

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm new to Kafka and I'm trying to connect with my Oracle DB, but none of the tutorials I found on the Internet works for me.
For now I have working Kafka and Zookeeper, and my docker-compose file looks like that:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I've tried to connect Kafka with Oracle DB locally, but it also doesn't work.
I've found demo project configured with Docker:
https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/oracle-and-kafka/docker-compose.yml
but it also doesn't work for me (error with Oracle). I'm wondering if my docker-compose has to be so big as in that project (I've been trying with one extra image for oracle and one for schema registry), because I need minimal working example.

Comment: Unclear how you tried to connect them locally, but maybe you should post your error with oracle here

Answer (score 0):

The linked Compose file seems to do what you want.

> wondering if my docker-compose has to be so big as in that project

You don't need ksql or postgres, so no, but you will want the kafka-connect service and the commands below it that setup the Debezium connector and Oracle driver dependencies